# Spring KafkaListener fails with Hibernate One to One unidirectional mapping

Tags: spring, hibernate, apache-kafka, spring-data-jpa

I have modelled One-to-One relationship in Hibernate using Spring data JPA. Here are my models:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Nationalized;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq-gen")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "seq-gen", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator", parameters = { @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "test_seq") })
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Nationalized
    @Column(name = "Name", length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String name;
}
```

---

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MapsId;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Nationalized;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="child")
public class Child
{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    private Parent parent;

    @Nationalized
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
}
```

Child table has foreign key relationship with Parent, which itself maps to child table's primary key using `@MapsId`. Note that it is a unidirectional relationship.

I am using Spring data jpa's `JpaRepository` to persist objects into database.

```
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Long>{}
```

---

```
public interface ChildRepository extends JpaRepository<Child, Long>{}
```

Inside my Service class, I have simple method that first persist's `Parent` object and then a `Child` object.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ServiceImpl
{
    @Autowired
    private ParentRepository parentRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ChildRepository childRepository;

    public void create()
    {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.setName("Parent");
        parent = parentRepository.save(parent);

        System.out.println(parent.getId());

        Child child = new Child();
        child.setName("Child");
        child.setParent(parent);
        childRepository.save(child);     // This line fails when using ControllerKafka
    }

}
```

I have created a RESTful controller, which has a `ServiceImpl` object autowired and it calls the appropriate method of Service class.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ControllerRestful
{
    @Autowired
    private ServiceImpl service;

    @PostMapping(value = "/test")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void create(@RequestBody UserDTO dto)
    {
        System.out.println(dto);
        service.create();
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Note that the Service class is independent of the Controller. I tested this endpoint locally and it persists the parent and child objects into the database.

Now when I switch to a kafka based controller, it throws an error while persisting.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class ControllerKafka
{
    @Autowired
    private ServiceImpl service;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "..", groupId = "..")
    @SendTo
    public void create(UserDTO dto, Acknowledgment acknowledgment)
    {
        service.create();
        System.out.println("Done");
        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
    }
}
```

Error log:

```
org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void ControllerKafka.create(UserDTO,org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment)' threw exception; 
nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: models.Parent;
nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: models.Parent; 
nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: models.Parent; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: models.Parent
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1899) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1887) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1792) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1719) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1617) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1348) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1064) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:972) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

How is it possible that Persisting `Child` object inside `ServiceImpl` fail in the case of `ControllerKafka` but not in `ControllerRestful`? Also if I remove the `@MapsId` attribute from `Child` and have different primary and foreign key for `Child` entity then there is no error while persisting.

Comment: use `@Transactional` on `create()` method, and remove `@MapsId`

Comment: @zlaval If I remove `@MapsId` is there some better way to model entities where Primary Key=Foreign Key?

Comment: With `@Transactional` it works fine, I am unsure as to how this happens. Without `@Transactional`, If I add a debug checkpoint at `childRepository.save(child)` and I check the database, Hibernate had already persisted `Parent` object and then when I resume from checkpoint and persist `Child` object, it fails.(Also if I abruptly close the program before resuming from checkpoint, it doesn't roll back).

Comment: Also why with `@RestController`, adding `@Transactional` was not needed?

Comment: With onetoone the child's fk will be the parents pk. If you do not use transactional, the two save method get different entitymanagers. So after the first save, the saved entity will be deprecated.

Comment: I want to have Child's PK=Parent's PK. That's the reason I added `MapsId`. Also `@Transactional` worked fine without removing `@MapsId`. Is there some reason why I should avoid using `@MapsId`?

Comment: No, you can use it if its needed for use case.

Comment: I am storing the reference to the saved parent entity after calling save method. So how can the saved entity deprecate?